# Regex Match a specific character between two strings

Tags: regex

I have a string where I need to replace a character.

Example:

`# ### This is a test, and I do not know what to do ### and here, we have some more information, all separated by comma`

So I can identify the text between the `###` like this:

```
(?=###)(.*)(?<=###)
```

But I only like to identify the **,** in the text between the ###.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry missed that the # was used to format the text

Comment: Do you just want to _match_ `###` with a comma in between, or else why do you want to match the comma itself?

Comment: Please also specify your pogramming language.

Comment: I need to find the , in the text in order to replace it. I use this actually as Regex search in Visual Code

Comment: And the most important question when you say "I am doing it in VSCode": is it in File Replace (the magnifying glass) or Document Search and Replace (CTRL+H)?

Comment: `(?<=###[^#]*),(?=[^#]*###)` will work in the latter case. And only if the pair of `###` is the only pair of `###` in the string. If you have `### ..., ...### ... , .... ###` both commas will be matched.